# hackerrank Circular Array Rotation Python

Tags: python

I tried to solve the Circular Array Rotation problem on HackerRank. 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation/problem

The following code passes all test cases except case #4, which gets a runtime error. Could someone point out the problem?

```
def circularArrayRotation(a, k, queries):

    if k < len(a):
        k = k
    elif k == len(a):
        k = 0
    else:
        k = k%a

    newList = []


    for val in queries:
        newInd = -k+val
        if abs(newInd) > len(a):
            newInd = newInd - (len(a)-1)
            newList += [a[newInd]]
        else:
            newList += [a[newInd]]        


    return newList
```

Comment: you need to make it fast as it is exceeding the  required time limit for that case

Comment: I don't know how to make it faster

Comment: Try to get the rotated array at once and in new list store the value of that query  index from rotated array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is correct. But is not running within that time limit for that case 4 only.

You are calculating the value each time for new queries, which is taking time.

What you can do is take the rotated array at once . and then run the queries on the rotated array. Save the result in the list and return it back.

```
def circularArrayRotation(a, k, queries):

    new_arr = a[-k%len(a):] + a[:-k%len(a)]
    # list slicing is done here.  it will get the right rotated array 

    result = []
    for i in queries:
        result.append(new_arr[i])
        # running queries on rotated array
    return result
```

using above method , list slicing is done in o(n) time . and then running the queries is done is o(1) time.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def circularArrayRotation(a, k, queries):
    j= len(a)

    for x in range(k):
        n=a[j-1]
        a.insert(0,n)
        a.pop(j)

    newList= []

    for m in queries:
        newList.append(a[m])

    return newList
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def circularArrayRotation(a, k, queries):
    #rotation
    for _ in range(k):
        a.insert(0, a.pop())
    #putting answer according to query
    ans = []
    for i in queries:
        ans.append(a[i])    
    return ans
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use deque A deque is a double-ended queue. It can be used to add or remove elements from both ends.

```
from collections import deque
    def circularArrayRotation(a, k, queries):
        result=[]
        a = deque(a) 
        a.rotate(k) 
        a = list(a) 

        for v in queries:
            result.append(a[v])

        return(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, but I was just solving this, so I figured might as well drop by, your else case is wrong! It should be `k = k % len(a)`, you wrote `k % a`, now I write c++, so don't know what that even does in python, but I'm pretty sure that doesn't automatically put in `len(a)` Besides, why are you bothering putting that in `if else` block just modulo every time, if it's smaller, no value change, for `=>` it fixes it to the right value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a deque is the approach to go, as AnkushRasgon's and shyamantha's answers. Here I post my version in Java. All tests passed.

```
static int[] circularArrayRotation(int[] a, int k, int[] queries) {

    LinkedList<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(a).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        list.push(list.pollLast());
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
        if (queries[i] < list.size()) {
            queries[i] = list.get(queries[i]);
        }
    }
    
    return queries;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def circularArrayRotation(a, k, queries):
    reverse_a = list(reversed(a))
    reverse_a_copy = reverse_a.copy()
    for x in range(k):
        item = reverse_a[x]
        reverse_a_copy.remove(item)
        reverse_a_copy.append(item)
    line = []
    for x in queries:
        line.append(list(reversed(reverse_a_copy))[x])
    return line
```

Comment: You should always try to provide some explanation when you try to help someone solving a problem, it's much better and appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
s=2
def rotateList(arr,d,n):
  arr[:]=arr[d-1:n]+arr[0:d-1]
  return arr

print(rotateList(a,5,len(a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

````
    for i in range(k):
        random_a = len(a)
        random_b = random_a - 1
        random_c = a.pop(random_b)
        a = [random_c] + a
    oz = a
    random_list = []
    for i in queries:
        z = oz[i]
        y = str(z)
        random_list.append(y)
    return random_list```
is this the correct answer
````

Comment: Better to give an explanation of your answer.